# How can I outsource a value that is the result of an addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Is there a way in which I would be able to get the value that is a result of user input from an addEventListener function to another addEventListener Function?

```
const btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1')
 btn1.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   const textContent = e.target.textContent
})

const btn2 = document.querySelector('#btn2')
 btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(textContent)
})
```

Comment: Declare `textContent` outside the block in global scope and call `btn2.click()`?

Comment: @TheMaster I would like to have the textContent value that comes as a result of clicking btn1 outsourced. This way, after the user clicks btn1, nothing should be displayed. After he clicks btn2, he should see 'btn1', which is the result of previously clicking btn1. Can you give me an example of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create non-anonymous listeners

```
function func1 (e) {
  //do task1
  func2(text);
}

function func2 (e) {
  if ((typeof e) == 'string') ...
  //do task2
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', func1);
btn2.addEventListener('click', func2);
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding. Would you be able to explain me through an example how to do this certain scenario? I will have two buttons. When the user clicks on the btn1, that will store the value of e.target.textContent of it, which should be 'btn1'. When the user clicks on btn2, btn1, should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to store value of previous buttons:

```html
  <body>
    <button id="btn1">btn1</button>
    <button id="btn2">btn2</button>
    <button id="btn3">btn3</button>
    <button id="btn4">btn4</button>
    <button id="btn5">Working Button</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    var text,body = document.querySelector('body');//declare text in global scope 
    body.addEventListener('click',e=>{
      let btn = e.target;
    if (btn.id !== 'btn5') text = btn.textContent;
     else alert(`You last clicked ${text}`);
    })
  </script>
```